# How to change the url of sign page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

I want to change the url of sign in page in magento 2

currently signin page url - customer/account/login

i need to change to url - signin

How can i change the url. Thanks..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772720/is-there-a-way-to-change-login-page-url-in-magento